# Proposed change leads to Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: support, bug, documentation, proposed-changes

In the C++ Documentation there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/44522) proposed change to user defined literals.  When clicking on it, it brings you the Oops! Something Bad Happened! page.

[image: Oops something bad happened]

This has been like this for at least a week.  First, what caused this and secondly, is there any way we can get this removed from the [proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b?tab=proposedchanges)?

---

EDIT:

It appears that the proposed change is no longer present(it was able to be rejected by a normal user).  Not sure if something was done or not.  If something was done could we please get an answer?

Comment: I'm seeing this error page as well after I submitted this [change](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/77102). It happens when I try viewing the topic itself, not the proposed change.

I noticed though that I don't get the error if I'm not logged in. I also had a colleague confirm that they can view the topic even if they are logged in with their account.